# BERT Model Fine Tuning and migrating to TF2

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, bert-language-model, tensorflow-model-garden

I executed this excellent tutorial:
https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-multi-label-text-classifier-using-bert-and-tensorflow-f188e0ecdc5d

I understood most of it except where model is being created. I would like to know it and migrate to TF2 bert.

1. When he says "Basically we load the pre-trained model and then train the last layer for classification task.", does it mean that he is freezing all the other layers and fine-tuning the last layer? This is the relevant code (in TF1) which I am not able to understand:

```py
def create_model(bert_config, is_training, input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids,
             labels, num_labels, use_one_hot_embeddings):
"""Creates a classification model."""
model = modeling.BertModel(
    config=bert_config,
    is_training=is_training,
    input_ids=input_ids,
    input_mask=input_mask,
    token_type_ids=segment_ids,
    use_one_hot_embeddings=use_one_hot_embeddings)

output_layer = model.get_pooled_output()

hidden_size = output_layer.shape[-1].value

output_weights = tf.get_variable(
    "output_weights", [num_labels, hidden_size],
    initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02))

output_bias = tf.get_variable(
    "output_bias", [num_labels], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

with tf.variable_scope("loss"):
    if is_training:
        # I.e., 0.1 dropout
        output_layer = tf.nn.dropout(output_layer, keep_prob=0.9)

    logits = tf.matmul(output_layer, output_weights, transpose_b=True)
    logits = tf.nn.bias_add(logits, output_bias)
    
    # probabilities = tf.nn.softmax(logits, axis=-1) ### multiclass case
    probabilities = tf.nn.sigmoid(logits)#### multi-label case
    
    labels = tf.cast(labels, tf.float32)
    tf.logging.info("num_labels:{};logits:{};labels:{}".format(num_labels, logits, labels))
    per_example_loss = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels, logits=logits)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(per_example_loss)

    return (loss, per_example_loss, logits, probabilities)
```

2. I went through the TF2 fine tuning tutorials for BERT, but how do I achieve the same? I am able to train other models where step 1 is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Use the official bert example :
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/classify_text_with_bert

Comment: Went through all tutorials in official TF2 site, it wasn't much help in migrating above code.

Comment: What you should do is rewriting the code in TF2 tutorial's way . There are many ugly codes in TF1

Comment: Yes I want to do just that, but didn't find many tutorials in working with BERT layers like its done above.

Comment: The link above is what you want .

Comment: It does the same thing : classify text with bert

Comment: Just classification is not what I want, I want to modify BERT layers.

Comment: Do you want to train bert by yourself rather than use the pretrained bert ?

Comment: No, use pretrained model and then tune it with my data like mentioned in the tutorial.

Comment: The official tutorials above does what you want : 1. loading a pretrained bert 2. fine-tune it ...